# How to add background image to a Windows form gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I wonder if there is any way to put an background image to the gridview in windows form ... I am using c#

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17648/Set-Image-as-Background-for-DataGridView

Comment: @HansPassant  Intellisense doesn't pick up the BackgroundImage, I was able to set it in the Form1 load event, thought it did not effect the datagridview

Comment: +1 for your comment. It's not every day someone acknowledges that I am correct, therefor that was a great comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the OnPaint event  you could do something like this

```
private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
         DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView) sender;
        int i = dgv.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.BackGround, new Rectangle(0, i, dgv.Width, (dgv.Height - i)));
    }
```

**EDIT**
This works to detect the Rows, but it doesn't seem to detect the UserAddRow option on the bottom, if that is a need. I am at a loss.

Comment: thanks this is a good way and it worked but the problem is that the image will be in front of the rows so the data will not appear

Comment: ok then you will need to detect rows, I will look at it for a moment.

Comment: Image is getting displayed but datagridview content is getting hided using this solution ,how to solve that? how to detect rows?